# Zurb Foundation is now 3 separate frameworks (Sites, Email, & Apps), should we reconsider the tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

### Overview:

The Foundation framework from Zurb was initially just a front-end framework. It is now three separate frameworks:

- [Foundation for Sites](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html)
- [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps.html)
- [Foundation for Email](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html)

Right now, these are all of the Foundation tags:

- [`zurb-foundation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation)
- [`zurb-foundation-5`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-5)
- [`zurb-foundation-6`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-6)
- [`zurb-foundation-apps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-apps)

---

### The Problem:

The tags [`zurb-foundation-5`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-5) & [`zurb-foundation-6`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-6) reference the [Foundation for Sites](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html) framework. If left unchanged, I see a problem down the road once the [Foundation for Apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps.html) & [Foundation for Email](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails.html) frameworks reach version 5. Most of the questions under [`zurb-foundation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) reference the [Foundation for Sites](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html) framework.

---

### Suggested Tag Changes:

- [`zurb-foundation`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) -> use as a "master" tag for all 3 frameworks
- [`zurb-foundation-5`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-5) -> `zurb-foundation-sites-5`
- [`zurb-foundation-6`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-6) -> `zurb-foundation-sites-6`
- [`zurb-foundation-apps`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation-apps) -> leave as is
- `zurb-foundation-sites` = new tag
- `zurb-foundation-emails` = new tag

Comment: On Meta am I supposed to put my suggestions in an answer to my own question or leave them in the question?

Comment: You're asking about the suggested changes, so in a question is fine.

Comment: Your email link is 404.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMedico! Question updated.